fmin_slsqp taking too long
I am using fmin_slsqp to find the weights that minimize mean squared error. The weights need to be positive. For each pair of X and y, it takes ~10 seconds. (Each X is (10, 1000) and y is (10,)). I have 8000 pairs that need to be calculated:(
Is there any error with the code, or it is just my data takes too long to converge? Is there any way to make this process efficient, like is there a way to calculate all 8000 pairs together?
def loss(W, X, y):
    return np.mean((y - X.dot(W))**2)

def get_result(X, y):
    w_start = [1/X.shape[1]] * X.shape[1]
    weights = fmin_slsqp(partial(loss_w, X=X, y=y),
                             np.array(w_start),
                             bounds=[(0.0, np.inf)] * X.shape[1],
                             disp=False)
    return weights


htop will tell you if the CPU utilisation is 100% during the operation. If it it then there's not much you can do unless it could be moved to a GPU

have you tried using a function to analytically calculate the partial derivatives, fprime, rather than using finite differences?

you can just use scipy.optimize.nnls which is ~3ms

This is not reproducible. A reproducible example would require values for X and y.

@Reinderien the docs for nnls say:Solve ``argmin_x || Ax - b ||_2`` for ``x>=0``. Can't A and b contain negative values? It's just the solution x>=0 which is what they want as they are using bounds=[(0.0, np.inf)] * X.shape[1]

ah, that's true. I'll adjust my answer to add a caveat.

As stated in the comments, you can use scipy.optimize.nnls to solve this problem, however this is not vectorized, so you have to loop over your initial array dimensions.
If you're willing to use other packages, you can use numba and nnls_numba (disclaimer I'm the author) to compile these loops and run them in parallel to solve it faster.
In SciPy versions 0.7 - 1.11, nnls is a wrapper around a fortran subroutine, in more recent versions of SciPy, it uses a different algorithm that is implemented in python. In nnls_numba you have access to numba compatible implementations of both of these functions: nnls_old and nnls_new respectively. Here's how to use these functions to solve your problem:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import nnls_numba
from scipy import optimize

rng = np.random.default_rng(69)

K, M, N = 8000, 10, 1000

A = rng.random((K, M, N))
x = rng.random((K, N))
x[:, ::3] *= -1
b = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', A, x) + rng.standard_normal((K, M))

def many_nnls_scipy(A, b):
    output = np.empty((A.shape[0], A.shape[2]))
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        output[i] = optimize.nnls(A[i], b[i])[0]
    return output

@nb.njit
def many_nnls_new(A, b, maxiter=-1):
    assert A.shape[:-1] == b.shape
    assert A.ndim == 3
    output = np.empty((A.shape[0], A.shape[2]))
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        output[i] = nnls_numba.nnls_new(A[i], b[i], None, 1e-9)[0]
    return output


def many_nnls_old(A, b, maxiter=-1):
    assert A.shape[:-1] == b.shape
    assert A.ndim == 3
    output = np.empty((A.shape[0], A.shape[2]))
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        output[i] = nnls_numba.nnls_old(A[i], b[i], maxiter)[0]
    return output

many_nnls_old_serial = nb.njit(many_nnls_old, parallel=False)
many_nnls_old_parallel = nb.njit(many_nnls_old, parallel=True)

Note, you can just use @njit on many_nnls_scipy (no import required) and it will use either nnls_new or nnls_old behind the scenes depending on which SciPy version you have installed.
Test and time:
result_scipy = many_nnls_scipy(A, b)
result_new = many_nnls_new(A, b)
result_old_serial = many_nnls_old_serial(A, b)
result_old_parallel = many_nnls_old_parallel(A, b)
    
assert np.allclose(result_new, result_scipy)
assert np.allclose(result_new, result_old_serial)
assert np.allclose(result_new, result_old_parallel)

%timeit -n 1 -r 1 many_nnls_scipy(A, b)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 many_nnls_new(A, b)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 many_nnls_old_serial(A, b)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 many_nnls_old_parallel(A, b)

Results:
16.9 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
13.8 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
960 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
138 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)


There's also the nnls_old_ function with which you can allocate the work arrays needed for the fortran subroutine yourself, but that is giving an error when I try it with your array dimensions.
Note, I'm not sure that nnls_new will work on windows.

This can be solved in one shot as a sparse block-diagonal problem. This takes a couple of seconds to solve. It might be sped up if you can offer some reasonable estimate of W to the x0 parameter of lsqr.
import numpy as np
import scipy


def solve(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    m, n, p = X.shape
    indptr = np.arange(m + 1, dtype=np.int32)
    indices = indptr[:-1]
    block_diag = scipy.sparse.bsr_array((X, indices, indptr))
    W = scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A=block_diag, b=y.ravel())[0]
    return W.reshape(m, p)


def demo() -> None:
    m = 8000
    n = 10
    p = 1000
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    X = rand.uniform(size=(m, n, p), low=-1, high=1)
    hidden_W = rand.uniform(size=(m, p), low=-1, high=1)
    y = X @ hidden_W[..., np.newaxis]
    W = solve(X, y)
    error = y - X@W[..., np.newaxis]
    print(f'{error.min()} <= error <= {error.max()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()

Note that this doesn't enforce non-negativity for the values of W. If that's crucial, then more time will need to be spent, either running a non-vectorised outer loop over something like scipy.optimize.nnls, or taking a solution from above and performing a conditional polishing step for values that are out of bounds.

how does this ensure W>=0?

It doesn't. The biggest challenge of the OP is to solve this problem efficiently given an outer loop of size 8000. If the bound is crucial, OP can perform a polishing step for any solutions that are out-of-bounds. I can't think of a way to do this that is both fully-vectorised and bounded.

well if they're willing to use other packages, they can use numba and nnls_numba (disclaimer I'm the author) to speed it up
